# TextExtraction is not working when tika config is enabled

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on SC 1.13. I am applying Tika Config to crawl the MS Docs and Pdf. Text Extraction is working good without any tika config and its taking the orginal content on the website. When I added the tika configuration the cralwer grabbing all headers, nav, footers. I am sharing my config is that anything wrong in the config.

#### crawler-conf.yaml

```
config: 
  topology.workers: 1
  topology.message.timeout.secs: 300
  topology.max.spout.pending: 100
  topology.debug: false

  fetcher.threads.number: 50

  # give 2gb to the workers
  worker.heap.memory.mb: 2048

  # mandatory when using Flux
  topology.kryo.register:
    - com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Metadata

  # metadata to transfer to the outlinks
  # used by Fetcher for redirections, sitemapparser, etc...
  # these are also persisted for the parent document (see below)
  # metadata.transfer:
  # - customMetadataName
  metadata.transfer:
   - seed

  # lists the metadata to persist to storage
  # these are not transfered to the outlinks
  metadata.persist:
   - _redirTo
   - error.cause
   - error.source
   - isSitemap
   - isFeed

  http.agent.name: "Anonymous Coward"
  http.agent.version: "1.0"
  http.agent.description: "built with StormCrawler Archetype 1.13"
  http.agent.url: "http://someorganization.com/"
  http.agent.email: "someone@someorganization.com"

  # The maximum number of bytes for returned HTTP response bodies.
  # The fetched page will be trimmed to 65KB in this case
  # Set -1 to disable the limit.
  http.content.limit: -1
  jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: false

  # FetcherBolt queue dump => comment out to activate
  # if a file exists on the worker machine with the corresponding port number
  # the FetcherBolt will log the content of its internal queues to the logs
  # fetcherbolt.queue.debug.filepath: "/tmp/fetcher-dump-{port}"

  parsefilters.config.file: "parsefilters.json"
  urlfilters.config.file: "urlfilters.json"

  # revisit a page daily (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.default: 1440

  # revisit a page with a fetch error after 2 hours (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.fetch.error: 120

  # never revisit a page with an error (or set a value in minutes)
  fetchInterval.error: -1

  # text extraction for JSoupParserBolt
  textextractor.include.pattern:
   - DIV[id="maincontent"]
   - DIV[itemprop="articleBody"]
   - ARTICLE

  textextractor.exclude.tags:
   - NAV
   - STYLE
   - SCRIPT

  # custom fetch interval to be used when a document has the key/value in its metadata
  # and has been fetched successfully (value in minutes)
  # fetchInterval.FETCH_ERROR.isFeed=true: 30
  # fetchInterval.isFeed=true: 10

  # configuration for the classes extending AbstractIndexerBolt
  # indexer.md.filter: "someKey=aValue"
  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
  - domain=domain
  - seed=seed

  # Metrics consumers:
  topology.metrics.consumer.register:
     - class: "org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
       parallelism.hint: 1
```

#### es-crawler.flux

```
name: "Crawler"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

    - resource: false
      file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
      override: true

    - resource: false
      file: "es-conf.yaml"
      override: true

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout"
    parallelism: 10

bolts:
  - id: "partitioner"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "fetcher"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "sitemap"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parse"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "index"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status_metrics"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "redirection_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.RedirectionBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1 

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "spout"
    to: "status_metrics"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE     

  - from: "partitioner"
    to: "fetcher"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["key"]

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "sitemap"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "parse"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "parse"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "parse"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "index"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"
  - from: "parse"
    to: "redirection_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "parser_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "parser_bolt"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "parser_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
      streamId: "tika"
```

#### es-injector.flux

```
name: "injector"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

    - resource: false
      file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
      override: true

    - resource: false
      file: "es-conf.yaml"
      override: true

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.FileSpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - "."
      - "seeds.txt"
      - true

bolts:
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: CUSTOM
      customClass:
        className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.URLStreamGrouping"
        constructorArgs:
          - "byHost"
      streamId: "status"
```

#### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.crawlernew.edu</groupId>
    <artifactId>crawlernew</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <stormcrawler.version>1.13</stormcrawler.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.apache.storm.flux.Flux</mainClass>
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Change></Change>
                                        <Build-Date></Build-Date>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <!-- The filters below are necessary if you want to include the Tika 
                                module -->
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2428 -->
                                    <artifact>org.apache.storm:flux-core</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org/apache/commons/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org/apache/http/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org/yaml/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-crawler-core</artifactId>
            <version>${stormcrawler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${stormcrawler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-crawler-tika</artifactId>
            <version>${stormcrawler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>flux-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### crawltoplology.java

```
package com.test.com;

// Replace with maven generated java and don't change the package name keep the maven generated package name

import org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;

import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Constants;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.DeletionBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.MetricsConsumer;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.CollapsingSpout;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.RedirectionBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt;


import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils;

public class CrawlTopology extends ConfigurableTopology {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableTopology.start(new CrawlTopology(), args);
    }

    @Override
    protected int run(String[] args) {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        int numWorkers = ConfUtils.getInt(getConf(), "topology.workers", 1);

        // set to the real number of shards ONLY if es.status.routing is set to
        // true in the configuration
        int numShards = 1;

        builder.setSpout("spout", new CollapsingSpout(), numShards);

        builder.setBolt("status_metrics", new StatusMetricsBolt())
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");

        builder.setBolt("partitioner", new URLPartitionerBolt(), numWorkers)
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");

        builder.setBolt("fetch", new FetcherBolt(), numWorkers).fieldsGrouping(
                "partitioner", new Fields("key"));

        builder.setBolt("sitemap", new SiteMapParserBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("fetch");

        builder.setBolt("parse", new JSoupParserBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("sitemap");

        builder.setBolt("indexer", new IndexerBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("parse");

         builder.setBolt("jsoup", new JSoupParserBolt())
                .localOrShuffleGrouping(
          "sitemap");

        builder.setBolt("shunt", new RedirectionBolt()).localOrShuffleGrouping("jsoup");    

        builder.setBolt("tika", new ParserBolt()).localOrShuffleGrouping("shunt",
          "tika");



        Fields furl = new Fields("url");

        builder.setBolt("status", new StatusUpdaterBolt(), numWorkers)
                .fieldsGrouping("fetch", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("sitemap", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("parse", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("indexer", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("jsoup", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)              
                .fieldsGrouping("shunt", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
                .fieldsGrouping("tika", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl);
        builder.setBolt("deleter", new DeletionBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("status",
                        Constants.DELETION_STREAM_NAME);

        conf.registerMetricsConsumer(MetricsConsumer.class);
        conf.registerMetricsConsumer(LoggingMetricsConsumer.class);

        return submit("crawl", conf, builder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The text extraction is not meant to work on the output of Tika, only JSoup. The latter is also better for processing HTML, you should use JSOUP for HTML documents and Tika for everything else and configure the topology as suggested [in the Tika README](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/tika/README.md).

Comment: Hi Julien, I tried to configure but nothing is working out on the existing above config and I added  `  builder.setBolt("indexer", new IndexerBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("shunt").localOrShuffleGrouping("tika");` in config and is that possible to share some test config on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  parser.mimetype.whitelist:
  - application/.+word.*
  - application/.+excel.*
  - application/.+powerpoint.*
  - application/.*pdf.*
```

Add this to your crawler-conf.yaml